# Karger's Algorithm Min-Cut on Directed Graphs

Tags: algorithm, kargers-algorithm

I am having a hard time understanding the logic of how Karger's Algorithm would work on an undirected graph. I know there are max-flow algorithms such as Ford-Fulkersson algorithm but I am not after using this algorithm on an undirected graph.

Could someone explain what the difference would be using Karger's Algorithm on a directed graph vs. Karger's Algorithm on an undirected graph.

Thanks in advance!